# Wordpress Archive Widget

Tags: wordpress

Ive looked around and cant find anything about this. Im quite supprised this isnt an option really but, im using the standard wordpress archive widget and i want to hide any month that does not have posts in it. How difficult can this be. Where is the code for this wideget and how can I add a piece of code to hide empty months?

Comment: This code is in wp-includes/default-widgets.php file

Comment: And you can simply copy the original widget code and create your own. Or look inside it for useful `apply_filters` hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply B... Can you expand further please on how i can edit this to hide the empty months.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug-in:

Norman Advanced Archive Widget: http://wordpress.org/plugins/norman-advanced-archive-widget/